# How to get the Authorization and Token URL?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Since about a half year I started by myself creating my own agent which should help me and other users to store their homework and vocabulary in Firebase. Now I finished all except the storing of in the database.

The problem why I'm not finished building Firebase store function is that I need to get the user id of the specific user. There are many samples like: `const userId = getUser().userId;` but I also read that the userId can change after 30 days and after changing the device. So I decided to do it with account linking from Actions on Google tutorial but the step two was just skipped where there where some fields like Authorization url or Token url, the problem is that I still dont know what to fill into this fields

I also saw some other tutorials where they have taken it from the firebase. Then I opened Firebase and enabled the google account signin in the Firebase Authentication tab. After this I went to the service account tab in the settings and clicked aon generate new private key then it downloaded a file but at the point Auth URI there was just this link https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth and when I pasted the link into the Authorization URL field it just throws the error "*Google accounts cannot be used as Auth endpoint urls per our Account Linking policy*".

Whats wrong with it? How can I get a right Authorization URL?

Comment: You will need to either implement oauth endpoints or use a third-party service like Auth0.

Comment: How to do it? Sorry I'm just a beginner with this :(

Comment: You may want to pick the OAuth provider first and then read their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Anonymous UserID is a little more consistent than what you're assuming. It will not be reset after 30 days - only after 30 days of non-use. It is also portable between devices, so the same user ID will be used for the same user account for the same Action no matter if they do it on their phone or on a speaker linked to their account.

As for what you're trying to do with Account Linking - there is nothing "wrong" with it - except it can't be used as the OAuth endpoint according to the [Account Linking policy](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#account_linking_and_identity) which states, in part

> When implementing account linking using OAuth, you must own your OAuth endpoint or have control over it with an OAuth service provider.

This means that you will need to implement your own OAuth endpoint or use an OAuth service provider such as [Auth0](https://auth0.com/). Google's OAuth implementation does not let you have control over the endpoint, so it is not a valid OAuth service provider for the Google Assistant.

If you implement your own OAuth service, you can consult the set of [minimal instructions](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow) that Google requires you to implement. In these steps, you would use Firebase Authentication to have your users authorize access for the Google Assistant. You would also create the two endpoints as part of this service - so we can't tell you what those endpoints should be.

Answer (score 0):

The userID is NOT reliable. You will get randomly generated user IDs all the time. In fact, likely you will get a randomly generated user ID in the same conversation with a person. When the device doesn't recognize the voice it sends a random user ID. Try this... Talk to your device, then go to the other side of the room and yell at it. Yep... Different user IDs, it didn't recognize your voice. Even worse, if the user hasn't trained it, no matter what happens it's a random user ID. I was getting about 2k implicit discoveries an hour at 1 point and over half of them were randomized. Don't trust the user ID. Anyone that thinks it's working isn't realizing they're getting a large portion of randomized requests from the exact same people.

Ok, so what to do if you don't actually need an "account" but you need to uniquely identify the user. What I did, is I setup an implicit oath account linking. That might sound daunting, but it's actually really simple. All you need is a web page/endpoint that will accept a GET request from Google (with some query string parameters). You will then generate a GUID, and redirect the request back to Google with the GUID in the accessToken. Then every request you receive for fulfillment you will have the accessToken you generated and behave exactly like you want, no randomization, no expiration, and it is beautiful (if only Google would treat the user ID the same way they treat the accessToken you wouldn't have to do this). The only downside is it requires the user to click a button in the app.

Here is a link to my action. Click "Link" and you can see it do it's thing.
https://assistant.google.com/services/a/id/7f0a927706286d9c/

And implicit linking here:
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-implicit-flow

Comment: This has changed somewhat... With the userStorage it has been improved over the userID. You can use the userStorage. I would recommend that you handle the case that the voice isn't recognized though. So, if you see an empty userStorage you should return a message of something like....  "It looks like this is the first time using <action>. If this is not correct ensure your voice is trained on the device."